# If $G=p^n$, how does the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ on $G/G'G^p$ induce a homomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\to GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, automorphism-group, p-groups

Say $G$ is finite $p$-group of order $p^n$. I know that $G/G'G^p$ is also a $p$-group, and let's say it has order $p^m$. I can define an action of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ on $G/G'G^p$ via $f*gG'G^p:=f(g)G'G^p$. I am confused as to how this action gives us a homomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \to GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$. In particular, I am confused how the homomorphism will be defined. I can't really see how the action is meant to be used to make the $m\times m$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to answer (what is $G'$??). I suspect there the answer is as follows: call the quotient $Q$. Then $Q$ is an abelian group of order $p^m$, and exponent $p$, hence is an $m$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space. Choosing a basis then any group acting on $Q$ embeds in $GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$ by its action on this basis

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Oh come on, $G'$ is standard notation for the derived group! The point is that the group $G/G'G^p$ is elementary abelian, which means that it can be regarded as a vector space of dimension $m$ over the field of order $p$.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$. I didn't mention because I thought this was standard notation. Can you please describe some more how would the embedding go?

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you please describe how the embedding when $G/G'G^p$ is viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ goes because I am not so sure about the details.

Comment: Elementary abelian $p$-groups can be regarded as vector spaces over ${\mathbb F}_p$, and their automorphisms are invertible linear transformations of that vector space, which correspond to elements of ${\rm GL}(m,p)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: But then wouldn't the map be from $\operatorname{Aut}(G/G'G^p) \to GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$? This is not the same as $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\to GL_m(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Comment: But @J.Doe any automorphism of $G$ fixes the characteristic subgroup $G'G^p$, and so maps to an automorphism of the group $G/G'G^p$ which (as Derek pointed out) is elementary abelian. Now any automorphism of an elementary abelian $p$-group $A$ is also an automorphism of the unique $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space structure on $A$, so there you are.

Comment: @DerekHolt I guess this is my bad then, being a non-group theorist I'd always write this $[G,G]$... the more you know